# Format a localized date in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

*This question is not for generic Java, but only for Codename One.*

I know that the `L10NManager` class provides the methods `formatDateLongStyle`, `formatDateShortStyle`, `formatDateTime`, `formatDateTimeMedium`, `formatDateTimeShort`, but their output is inconsistent between platforms (Simulator, Android, iOS, etc.). Moreover, even if their output could be consistent, it's not exactly as I need it.

I need to format the output localized string exactly as requested, that is: short localized day of week, day of month, long localized month, year (four digits), a minus sign with spaces (" - "), hours (24h, two digits), colon (":"), minutes. I don't want seconds, I need an output exactly in this format.

Is there any API for that in Codename One? Any hint? Thank you

Comment: Can `com.codename1.l10n.DateFormatSymbols` be useful for that? I didn't understand the use of that class. If the platforms cannot directly localize the names of week days and months, can we do that using the language bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` has localization support by localizing the resource bundle with the following strings:

```
private static final String L10N_ZONE_LONGNAME = "ZONE_LONGNAME_";
private static final String L10N_ZONE_SHORTNAME = "ZONE_SHORTNAME_";
private static final String L10N_ZONE_LONGNAME_DST = "ZONE_LONGNAME_DST_";
private static final String L10N_ZONE_SHORTNAME_DST = "ZONE_SHORTNAME_DST_";
private static final String L10N_WEEKDAY_LONGNAME = "WEEKDAY_LONGNAME_";
private static final String L10N_WEEKDAY_SHORTNAME = "WEEKDAY_SHORTNAME_";
private static final String L10N_MONTH_LONGNAME = "MONTH_LONGNAME_";
private static final String L10N_MONTH_SHORTNAME = "MONTH_SHORTNAME_";
private static final String L10N_AMPM = "AMPM_";
private static final String L10N_ERA = "ERA_";
```

So for instance AM/PM can be localized by defining `AMPM_AM` and `AMPM_PM` respectively.

You can also use `DateFormatSymbols` directly but that's a bit painful as you need to do it per `SimpleDateFormat` instance.

Comment: Thank you Shai, it was easier than I thought. After your answer, I added another answer with a full implementation of what I requested (an example can be useful for other people). However, I would ask you to make your answer a bit more clear, because I understood how to localize using `DateFormatSymbols`, but I didn't understand how I can localize using the resource bundle, that should be better. For example, if I add the translations in the format `"MONTH_LONGNAME_January": "Gennaio"`, `"MONTH_LONGNAME_February": "Febbraio"`, etc., they are not used by `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 2):

Examples of patterns compatible with the Codename One SimpleDateFormat class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Full implementation example to localize in Italian the date formatted as I requested.
Note that the first day to localize in the `weekDays` and `shortWeekDays` arrays is Sunday.

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());

        String[] weekDays = {"Domenica", "Lunedì", "Martedì", "Mercoledì", "Giovedì", "Venerdì", "Sabato"};
        String[] shortWeekDays = {"Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Gio", "Ven", "Sab"};
        String[] months = {"Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"};
        String[] shortMonths = {"Gen", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mag", "Giu", "Lug", "Ago", "Set", "Ott", "Nov", "Dic"};
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
        simpleDateFormat.applyPattern("EEE d MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM yyyy - HH:mm");
        simpleDateFormat.getDateFormatSymbols().setWeekdays(weekDays);
        simpleDateFormat.getDateFormatSymbols().setShortWeekdays(shortWeekDays);
        simpleDateFormat.getDateFormatSymbols().setMonths(months);
        simpleDateFormat.getDateFormatSymbols().setShortMonths(shortMonths);
        String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        hi.add(new Label(date));
        hi.show();
```

Example of output:

```
Mer 11 Settembre 2019 - 11:51
```